# clicking mobile menu is deleting content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a concept where when you click on a link in the navigation the content gets replaced and I'd like to optimize my website for mobile devices as well but I have a problem where when I try to open the menu it deletes the content. It comes back when you click the link in the menu but deletes it again when closing the menu.

What did I try? I tried adding a feature that automatically closes the mobile menu when clicking on a link, I also tried giving the classes for the buttons in the mobile navigation different names to treat them separately.

My code (I tried to shorten it) & [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HcJanni/y7gLfth3/47/):

```js
// change activenav class, show the clicked element only and hide the others https://codepen.io/MohdHussein/pen/MWKEvdp


// grab all the buttons
let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");

// loop through the buttons using for..of 
for (let button of Buttons) {
  // listen for a click event 
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // et = event target
    const et = e.target;
    // slect activenav class
    const activenav = document.querySelector(".activenav");
    // check for the button that has activenav class and remove it
    if (activenav) {
      activenav.classList.remove("activenav");
    }
    // add activenav class to the clicked element 
    et.classList.add("activenav");

    // select all classes with the name content
    let allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.contentsec');

    // loop through all content classes
    for (let contentsec of allContent) {
      // display the content if the class has the same data-attribute as the button 
      if (contentsec.getAttribute('data-number') === button.getAttribute('data-number')) {
        contentsec.style.display = "block";
      }
      // if it's not equal then hide it.
      else {
        contentsec.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
}





let burger = document.getElementById('burger'),
  nav = document.getElementById('main-nav');

burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle('is-open');
  nav.classList.toggle('is-open');
});
```

```css
/* ALLGEMEINES */

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

body {
  height: 5000px;
}

#wrap {
  scroll-margin-top: 130px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  top: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 3em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-table;
  margin-left: 0.25vw;
  padding: 0.25vw;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navb {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  color: black !important;
}

.navb:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}

#navbar {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#navwrapper {
  background: darkgray;
  height: 200px;
}


/* Switching content on button press */

.selectSection {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.selectSection button {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  outline: none;
}

.activenav {
  color: black !important;
}


/* hides every element except the first */

.contentsec:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.contentSection {
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
  display: grid;
}


/* END */


/* CONTENT */

.uberschrift {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/* BURGER MENU */


/* Main menu positionning */

.mobilecontainer {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all .375s;
}

.main-nav.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1100;
  visibility: visible;
}


/* White band effect */

.main-nav::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: -15px;
  background: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(-120%);
  transition: all .275s .1s;
}

.main-nav.is-open::before {
  transform: skew(-14deg) translateX(0);
}


/* Skewing effect on menu links */

.main-nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 93%;
  /* Should be 100%, but we have a notice message :D */
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: translateX(-18%) skew(-16deg);
}

.main-nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem 0;
  text-align: right;
  transform: skew(16deg);
}


/* Apparition effect on links */

.main-nav button {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.main-nav.is-open button {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.main-nav li:nth-child(1) a {
  transition: all 275ms 175ms
}

.main-nav li:nth-child(2) a {
  transition: all 275ms 225ms
}

.main-nav li:nth-child(3) a {
  transition: all 275ms 275ms
}

.main-nav li:nth-child(4) a {
  transition: all 275ms 325ms
}

.main-nav li:nth-child(5) a {
  transition: all 275ms 375ms
}


/* Decoration */

.main-nav ul,
.main-nav li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav button {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0;
  color: #5A3B5D;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Burger Style: @see: https://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/full/oMZNXy */

.open-main-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 1200;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open-main-nav:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#burger {
  position: fixed;
  float: right;
}

.burger {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skew(5deg);
  transition: all .275s;
  margin-top: 2vw;
}

.burger:after,
.burger:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all .275s;
}

.burger:after {
  transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(-2px) skew(-20deg);
}

.burger:before {
  transform: translateY(-16px) skew(-10deg);
}


/* Toggle State part */

.is-open .burger {
  transform: skew(5deg) translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.is-open .burger:before {
  transform: translateY(0px) skew(-10deg) rotate(75deg);
}

.is-open .burger:after {
  transform: translateY(-12px) translateX(10px) skew(-20deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

.is-open .burger,
.is-open .burger:after,
.is-open .burger:before {
  background: #000;
}


/* MENU Text part */

.burger-text {
  display: block;
  font-size: .675rem;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
  margin-top: .5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.is-open .burger-text {
  color: #000;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Notice */

.notice {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  color: #5A3B5D;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.notice strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.notice button {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  background: #FEDC2A;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* BURGER MENU END */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8vw;
    top: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 3em;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul li {
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: -1.5em;
    padding-left: -1.5em;
  }
  .navb {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #navwrapper {
    background: darkgray;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .mobilecontainer {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav id="navwrapper">
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top selectSection">
      <h1 id="titel">Headline</h1>
      <ul id="widenav">
        <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" type="button" data-number="1" class="activenav navb">content1</button></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" type="button" data-number="2" class="navb">content2</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="mobilecontainer navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top selectSection">
      <button id="burger" class="open-main-nav">
            <span class="burger"></span>
            <span class="burger-text">Menu</span>
        </button>
      <div class="main-nav" id="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" type="button" data-number="1" class="activenav mobilenavb">content1</button></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><button onclick="location.href='#wrap'" type="button" data-number="2" class="mobilenavb">content2</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="wrap" class="contentSection wrapper">
    <!-- SECTION 1 -->
    <section id="content1" class="contentsec" data-number="1">
      <div>
        <h1>head1</h1>
        <h2>content1</h2>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- SECTION 2 -->
    <section id="content2" class="contentsec" data-number="2">
      <div>
        <h1>head2</h1>
        <h2>content2</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are there 3 CDN linked for `jquery` !

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? And why do you add three **different** versions of jQuery to your page?

Comment: code edited, my mistake sorry

Comment: Your `#burger` button is contained inside a `.selectSection`, meaning `document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button")` has selected that button as well, and so you add the same click handler to it, as to all your other buttons. Inside that click handler, you set all `.contentsec` to `display:none`, if their `data-number` attribute doesn’t match that of the button. `#burger` doesn’t have any `data-number` attribute to begin with, so that comparison yields false for _all_ `.contentsec` elements, and so you are hiding them all.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `let Buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".selectSection button");` u also adding handler for menu button, then here

```
if (contentsec.getAttribute('data-number') === button.getAttribute('data-number')) {
    contentsec.style.display = "block";
  }
  // if it's not equal then hide it.
  else {
    contentsec.style.display = "none";
  }
```

u dont have data-number on menu button, so u hiding content every time u clicking on menu button. Add maybe 1 more class to selector for buttons.